# ServerScriptService.DataStore:41: Expected 'end' (to close 'function' at line 31), got <eof>

Tags: lua, roblox

I know these questions are typically easy fixes, but I have spent the past hour playing with parenthesis and 'end' to attempt to solve the error referenced in the title. The code for my DataStore (where the issue is):

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
  local Ser = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
  local Storage = Ser:GetDataStore('StatsDataStore')
  plr:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
  local data = Storage:GetAsync(plr.UserId)
  if data then
    plr.leaderstats.Credits.Value = data.credits
    plr.leaderstats.Power.Value = data.power
    plr.leaderstats.Kills.Value = data.kills
    plr.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value = data.rebirths
  end
end)
```

Comment: there is no end missing in this snippet. the error must be somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

The error is due to the parenthesis ')' at last end statement.